# Combine Two strings together

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to combine two strings together, but have any duplicates inside be replaces.
I'm thinking string1 would supersede string2.

So if I have:

```
str1 = 'user { id name } roles { id name }';
str2 = 'user { roles match } permissions { id role_id }';
```

I would like to end up with:

```
'user { roles match } roles { id name } permissions { id role_id }'
```

I tried doing:

```
str1.replace(/[a-z]* {.*}/g, str2)
```

But this ends up replacing the first string with the second string.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: Explain how you made the output string out of str1 & str2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be a little overkill for what you need, but it should be pretty flexible and robust if you need to extend it or handle more possibilities.

```js
str1 = 'user { id name } roles { id name }';
str2 = 'user { roles match } permissions { id role_id }';

//Return an object containing the key and object parts of a string
//getParts(str1) -> {user: '{ id name }', roles: '{ id name }'}
function getParts(s) {
  var out = {};
  var re = /([a-z]+) ({.*?})/gi;
  match = re.exec(s);
  while (match) {
    out[match[1]] = match[2];
    match = re.exec(s);
  }
  return out;
}

//Takes in the parts object created by getParts and returns a space
//separated string. Exclude is an array of strings to exclude from the result.
//makeString(getParts(str1), ['user']) -> 'roles {id name}'
function makeString(parts, exclude) {
  if (typeof exclude === 'undefined') {
    exclude = [];
  }
  var out = [];
  for (var key in parts) {
    if (!parts.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      continue;
    }
    if (exclude.indexOf(key) !== -1) {
      continue;
    }
    out.push(key + ' ' + parts[key]);
  }
  return out.join(' ');
}

//Combines two strings in the desired format, with s2 keys taking precedence
//in case of any duplicates
function combine(s1, s2) {
  var p1 = getParts(s1);
  var p2 = getParts(s2);
  return makeString(p1, Object.keys(p2)) + ' ' + makeString(p2);
}

console.log(combine(str1, str2));
```

Comment: Nice use of the magic of `exec`. "If your regular expression uses the "g" flag, you can use the exec() method multiple times to find successive matches in the same string. When you do so, the search starts at the substring of str specified by the regular expression's lastIndex property"